# Creating flexible, iterative field name in Python function or loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I am creating a DataFrame with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd  
df1= pd.DataFrame({'segment': ['abc','abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz','xyz'], 
                   'prod_a_clients': [5,0,12,25,0,2,5,24,0,1,21,7],
                   'prod_b_clients': [15,6,0,12,8,0,17,0,2,23,15,0]                    })

abc_seg= df1[(df1['segment']=='abc')] 
xyz_seg= df1[(df1['segment']=='xyz')]  

seg_prod= df1[(df1['segment']=='abc') & (df1['prod_a_clients']>0)]   
abc_seg['prod_a_mean'] = statistics.mean(seg_prod['prod_a_clients'])

seg_prod= df1[(df1['segment']=='abc') & (df1['prod_b_clients']>0)]   
abc_seg['prod_b_mean'] = statistics.mean(seg_prod['prod_b_clients'])                            

seg_prod= df1[(df1['segment']=='xyz') & (df1['prod_a_clients']>0)]   
xyz_seg['prod_a_mean'] = statistics.mean(seg_prod['prod_a_clients'])

seg_prod= df1[(df1['segment']=='xyz') & (df1['prod_b_clients']>0)]   
xyz_seg['prod_b_mean'] = statistics.mean(seg_prod['prod_b_clients'])                              

segs_combined= [abc_seg,xyz_seg]
df2= pd.concat(segs_combined, ignore_index=True) 
print(df2)
```

As you can see from the result I need to calculate a mean for every product and segment combination I have. I'm going to be doing this for 100s of products and segments. I have tried many different ways of doing this with a loop or a function and have gotten close with something like the following:

```
def prod_seg(sg,prd):
    seg_prod= df1[(df1['segment']==sg) & (df1[prd+'_clients']>0)]   
    prod_name= prd+'_clients'   
    col_name= prd+'_average'
    df_name= sg+'_seg'
    df_name+"['"+prd+'_average'+"']"=statistics.mean(seg_prod[prod_name])
    return
```

The issue is that I need to create a unique column for every iteration and the way I am doing it above is obviously not working.

Is there any way I can recreate what I did above in a loop or function?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `.groupby()`? Maybe `print(df1.groupby(df1["segment"]).mean())`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use groupby in order to calculate the mean per group. Also, replace the 0 with nan and it gets skipped by the mean calculation. The script then looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'segment': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz',
                                'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                    'prod_a_clients': [5, 0, 12, 25, 0, 2, 5, 24, 0, 1, 21, 7],
                    'prod_b_clients': [15, 6, 0, 12, 8, 0, 17, 0, 2, 23, 15, 0]})

df1.set_index("segment", inplace=True, drop=True)
df1[df1 == 0] = np.nan
mean_values = dict()
for seg_key, seg_df in df1.groupby(level=0):
    mean_value = seg_df.mean(numeric_only=True)
    mean_values[seg_key] = mean_value

results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mean_values)
print(results)
```

The results is:

```
                  abc    xyz
prod_a_clients  14.00  10.00
prod_b_clients  10.25  14.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop, you can derive the same result by first using `where` on the 0s in the clients columns (which replaces 0s with NaN); then `groupby` the "segments" column and transform the "mean" method.

The point of `where` is that mean method by default skips NaN values, so by converting 0s with NaN, we make sure 0s are not considered for the mean.

`transform(mean)` transforms the mean (which is an aggregate value) to align with the original DataFrame, so every row has a matching mean value.

```
clients = ['prod_a_clients', 'prod_b_clients']
out = (df1.join(df1[['segment']]
                .join(df1[clients].where(df1[clients]>0))
                .groupby('segment').transform('mean')
                .add_suffix('_mean')))
```

Output:

```
   segment  prod_a_clients  prod_b_clients  prod_a_clients_mean  prod_b_clients_mean  
0      abc               5              15                 14.0                10.25  
1      abc               0               6                 14.0                10.25  
2      abc              12               0                 14.0                10.25  
3      abc              25              12                 14.0                10.25  
4      abc               0               8                 14.0                10.25  
5      xyz               2               0                 10.0                14.25  
6      xyz               5              17                 10.0                14.25  
7      xyz              24               0                 10.0                14.25  
8      xyz               0               2                 10.0                14.25  
9      xyz               1              23                 10.0                14.25  
10     xyz              21              15                 10.0                14.25  
11     xyz               7               0                 10.0                14.25
```